# Trying to add answers in a list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My code is basic as my question:

Why I am not able to add the answers after click on `Radio Button` and also `print` the answer on the console with this code?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyQuestion(),
    );
  }
}

class MyQuestion extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyQuestion({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyQuestion> createState() => _MyQuestionState();
}

class _MyQuestionState extends State<MyQuestion> {
  final List<String> selectedAnswers = [];

  void chooseAnswer(String answer) {
    setState(() {
      selectedAnswers.add(answer);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: FirstScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<FirstScreen> createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  int selectedOption = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Seja Bem-Vindo (a) ao Questionário TAS-20',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.amber,
            fontSize: 16,
          ),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const MyQuestion(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Radio(
                  value: 1,
                  groupValue: selectedOption,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedOption = value as int;
                      _MyQuestionState().chooseAnswer(value as String);
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Radio(
                  value: 2,
                  groupValue: selectedOption,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedOption = value as int;
                      _MyQuestionState().chooseAnswer(value as String);
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Radio(
                  value: 3,
                  groupValue: selectedOption,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedOption = value as int;
                      _MyQuestionState().chooseAnswer(value as String);
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Radio(
                  value: 4,
                  groupValue: selectedOption,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedOption = value as int;
                      _MyQuestionState().chooseAnswer(value as String);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Text('Answer 1'),
                Text('Answer 2'),
                Text('Answer 3'),
                Text('Answer 4')
              ],
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text('Next'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I think my main problem is how to use this chunk of code into FirstScreen statefull Widget:

```
 final List<String> selectedAnswers = [];

  void chooseAnswer(String answer) {
    setState(() {
      selectedAnswers.add(answer);
    });
  }
```

I tried to include `_MyQuestionState().chooseAnswer(value as String);` at `onChanged` argument but its not working.

Also at the same time I answer I am not able to include as a print on the console the answer that the user chosed.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that need to be fixed:

1. You can't convert an `int` to a `String` by using the type cast `as String`. You should use the [`toString`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Object/toString.html) method instead, so change `value as String` to `value.toString()`.
2. When you call `_MyQuestionState().chooseAnswer`, you're actually creating a new instance of  `_MyQuestionState()`, and not controlling the existing state. If you want to be able to call the `chooseAnswer` from `FirstScreen`, you should pass the callback in `_MyQuestionState` like this:

   ```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold( // (1) remove the 'const'
       body: Padding(
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
         child: FirstScreen(chooseAnswer: chooseAnswer), // (2) pass the 'chooseAnswer' method
       ),
     );
   }
   ```

   In `FirstScreen`, add the `chooseAnswer` parameter:

   ```
   class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
     const FirstScreen({super.key, required this.chooseAnswer}); // (1) add it in the constructor

     final void Function(String) chooseAnswer; // (2) add the property

     @override
     State<FirstScreen> createState() => _FirstScreenState();
   }
   ```

   After that, change the call of `_MyQuestionState().chooseAnswer` to `widget.chooseAnswer`. Additionally, you don't need to put this call inside `setState`, so your `onChanged` callback should look like this:

   ```
   onChanged: (value) {
     setState(() {
       selectedOption = value!; // (1) to convert 'int?' to 'int', just put '!' after the value
     });
     widget.chooseAnswer(value.toString()); // (2) call 'chooseAnswer' like this and move it outside the setState
   }
   ```

---

**FULL CODE**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyQuestion(),
    );
  }
}

class MyQuestion extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyQuestion({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyQuestion> createState() => _MyQuestionState();
}

class _MyQuestionState extends State<MyQuestion> {
  final List<String> selectedAnswers = [];

  void chooseAnswer(String answer) {
    setState(() {
      selectedAnswers.add(answer);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: FirstScreen(chooseAnswer: chooseAnswer),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstScreen({super.key, required this.chooseAnswer});

  final void Function(String) chooseAnswer;

  @override
  State<FirstScreen> createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  int selectedOption = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Seja Bem-Vindo (a) ao Questionário TAS-20',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.amber,
            fontSize: 16,
          ),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const MyQuestion(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Radio(
                  value: 1,
                  groupValue: selectedOption,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedOption = value!;
                    });
                    widget.chooseAnswer(value.toString());
                  },
                ),
                Radio(
                  value: 2,
                  groupValue: selectedOption,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedOption = value!;
                    });
                    widget.chooseAnswer(value.toString());
                  },
                ),
                Radio(
                  value: 3,
                  groupValue: selectedOption,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedOption = value!;
                    });
                    widget.chooseAnswer(value.toString());
                  },
                ),
                Radio(
                  value: 4,
                  groupValue: selectedOption,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedOption = value!;
                    });
                    widget.chooseAnswer(value.toString());
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Text('Answer 1'),
                Text('Answer 2'),
                Text('Answer 3'),
                Text('Answer 4')
              ],
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text('Next'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you run your code, you'll see an erorr:

```
Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'int'
```

This is because in your code, you are doing:

```dart
selectedOption = value as int; // int over here
_MyQuestionState().chooseAnswer(value as String); // using the `int` but it's really a String
```

value is an `int`, not a `String`, as I have commented

To fix the issue just call `.toString`:

```dart
selectedOption = value as int;
_MyQuestionState().chooseAnswer(value.toString());
```

that fixes **problem 1**

But then, if you run your code again, you'll encounter **another problem** once selecting a checkbox:

```dart
setState() called in constructor: _MyQuestionState#4077c(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)
```

This is because the Widget is not yet mounted/created. So, to solve the issue, you can use a short deelay:

```dart
  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), () { // --> Use a delay
      setState(() {
        selectedOption = value as int;
        _MyQuestionState().chooseAnswer(value.toString());
      });
    });
```

Also, you should remove the `setState` from `choooseAnswer`

```dart
  void chooseAnswer(String answer) {
    setState(() { // <-- remove this
      selectedAnswers.add(answer);
    });
  }
```

and call it in the `onChanged`.

Your complete working code should look like:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyQuestion(),
    );
  }
}

class MyQuestion extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyQuestion({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyQuestion> createState() => _MyQuestionState();
}

class _MyQuestionState extends State<MyQuestion> {
  final List<String> selectedAnswers = [];

  void chooseAnswer(String answer) {
    selectedAnswers.add(answer);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: FirstScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<FirstScreen> createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  int selectedOption = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Seja Bem-Vindo (a) ao Questionário TAS-20',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.amber,
            fontSize: 16,
          ),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const MyQuestion(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Radio(
                  value: 1,
                  groupValue: selectedOption,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedOption = value as int;
                        _MyQuestionState().chooseAnswer(value.toString());
                      });
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Radio(
                  value: 2,
                  groupValue: selectedOption,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedOption = value as int;
                        _MyQuestionState().chooseAnswer(value.toString());
                      });
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Radio(
                  value: 3,
                  groupValue: selectedOption,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedOption = value as int;
                        _MyQuestionState().chooseAnswer(value.toString());
                      });
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Radio(
                  value: 4,
                  groupValue: selectedOption,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedOption = value as int;
                        _MyQuestionState().chooseAnswer(value.toString());
                      });
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Text('Answer 1'),
                Text('Answer 2'),
                Text('Answer 3'),
                Text('Answer 4')
              ],
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text('Next'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is amazing @MendelG Thanks for your time. For a beginner the use of Future.delayed is ok? Or it is a more advanced skill?

Comment: This solution will lead into bugs. First, calling `_MyQuestionState().chooseAnswer` is vague, as it will create a new instance of `_MyQuestionState` every time instead of modifying the existing state. Second, relying on the delay to "fix" the mounted issue is risky. Third, because inside `chooseAnswer` there is no `setState` anymore, if later on there need to be a widget inside `MyQuestion` that renders what's inside `selectedAnswers`, it won't be reactive to the updates made to the list.

Comment: @JohnBonesJohnBones using `Future.delayed` is sometimes needed even for beginners, but not in this case. See my answer to see how to deal with the issues.

Comment: @JohnBonesJohnBones I agree with Dhafin. I dont think this is the best solution, but was just showing how to accomplish with your code.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I agree with your answer. I was just showing the OP how to integrate it with thier current approach. +1.